# Question on an $\mathbb{R} $-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Define $[n] = \{1,\ldots, n\} $, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and define the $2^n$- dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-algebra $C_n$ as follows:

**Notation**: Basis is $e_I$, where $I \subset \mathbb{N}$ and let $e_i$ = $e_I$ when $I = \{i\}$.

Multiplication in $C_n$ is defined by the rules $e_\emptyset = 1$, $e
_ie_j = -e_je_i$ for $i \neq j \in [n]$, $e_i^2 = 1$ for $i \in [n]$, and $e_I = e_{i_1}, \ldots, e_{i_k}$ where $I=\{i_1, \ldots,i_k\}$ with $i_1 < \ldots < i_k \in [n]$

**Question**: Right multipilcation by $x \in C_n$ is a $\mathbb{R}$-linear endomorphism, show that:

$$tr(e_I) = \begin{cases} 2^n &\mbox{if } I = \emptyset\\ 
0 & \mbox{if } I \neq \emptyset \end{cases} $$

Comment: Hints: If $I=\emptyset$, how does $e_I$ act? What is the dimension of $C_n$? How does $e_1$ act on even resp. odd subspaces of $C_n$?...

Comment: I don't see a question.

Comment: The question asks to show that $$tr(e_I) = \begin{cases} 2^n &\mbox{if } I = \emptyset\\ 
0 & \mbox{if } I \neq \emptyset \end{cases} $$